# using IIF function one parameter / field to be displayed basis combination of Multiple fields

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need a help on MS Access. Below are 3 tables to be used.

Logic:

I need a query which should fetch VATRATE available in `VAT_Inclusion` basis combination of GL, branch and domicile (in same table). Example:

```
VAT_Inclusion

Branch|Local_GL_Start|Local_GL_end|Domicile|VATRATE
------+--------------+------------+--------+-------
 21   |40000         |50000       |UK      |9
```

Details of domicile: to be fetched basis local customer id from `GRT` table and local customer id in `Domicile` table. `GRT` does not contain domicile but `Domicile` does.

For your reference I have prepared a query (given below at the end) but facing some issues.

Output in `GRT` table format:

```
Branch|Local_GL| Local_CUST_ID|VAT RATE
------+--------+--------------+--------
21    | 40010  |  CUST_223    |9
```

The output should have data from `GRT` which contains Branch as 21 and Local GL between range given in `VAT_Inclusion` (here its 40010).

1. GRT Table (source /raw file)

   `Branch|Local_GL| Local_CUST_ID`
2. VAT_Inclusion Table: GL Range to be selected

   `Branch|Local_GL_Start|Local_GL_end|Domicile|VATRATE`
3. Domicile Table

   `Local_CUST_ID|Domicile`

```
select GRT.*,IIF(GRT.Branch=VAT_Inclusion.Branch) and (GRT.local_GL between AT_Inclusion.Local_GL_Start
and AT_Inclusion.Local_GL_Start) and (VAT_Inclusion.Domicile=Domicile_out.Domicile),VAT_Inclusion.VATRATE, "7") from
VAT_Inclusion, GRT, (select GRT.Local_CUST_ID, DOMICILE.Local_CUST_ID, DOMICILE.DOMICILE from GRT, DOMICILE
where GRT.Local_CUST_ID=DOMICILE.Local_CUST_ID) AS Domicile_out
where GRT.Branch=VAT_Inclusion.Branch
AND GRT.local_GL between AT_Inclusion.Local_GL_Start and AT_Inclusion.Local_GL_Start
AND VAT_Inclusion.Domicile=Domicile_out.Domicile
```

Request your help in resolving the issue. It is not showing VAT Rate as desired. Its only showing 7 as VAT Rate for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL had a couple spelling mistakes (AT instead of VAT), and the ")' before the 'AND' needs to be removed.  Try the following:

```
SELECT GRT.*, IIf([GRT].[Branch]=[VAT_Inclusion].[Branch] And ([GRT].[local_GL] Between [VAT_Inclusion].[Local_GL_Start] And [VAT_Inclusion].[Local_GL_Start]) And ([VAT_Inclusion].[Domicile]=[Domicile_out].[Domicile]),[VAT_Inclusion].[VATRATE],"7") AS Expr1
FROM VAT_Inclusion, GRT, (select GRT.Local_CUST_ID, DOMICILE.Local_CUST_ID, DOMICILE.DOMICILE 
from GRT, DOMICILE 
where GRT.Local_CUST_ID=DOMICILE.Local_CUST_ID)  AS Domicile_out
WHERE (((GRT.Branch)=[VAT_Inclusion].[Branch]) AND ((GRT.local_GL) Between [VAT_Inclusion].[Local_GL_Start] And [VAT_Inclusion].[Local_GL_Start]) AND ((VAT_Inclusion.Domicile)=[Domicile_out].[Domicile]));
```